# Add or remove uiview according to conditions in Objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way I can add or remove a view from my view controller based on some conditions, so it wouldn't take up space on the screen?

I'm looking for something like `View.GONE` in Android. I know there's `[view setHidde:YES]` but it only makes it invisible without releasing the space.

Comment: if you are using auto layout, then play with constraints. if you want to clean up remove from the parent view then `removeFromSuperview`...

Comment: If  you put it in stack view then space will be released

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
//needToRemoveView is a boolean flag and based on that you can remove view
if (needToRemoveView) { 

    [self.viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

}
```

`removeFromSuperview` method actually removes the view form its super view and releases the memory occupied by view and the spaces on the screen.

Where as `setHidden:` method doesn't not actually removes the view instead it hides the view and the space occupied by the view will be there(on screen as well as in memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a different way too.

Along with `setHidden` you can disable view's constraints to release the space. But remember to have a strong reference to disabled constraints, because they'll be released otherwise.

```
+---------------------------+
| V0: Some view             |
+---------------------------+ :
                              | constraint with priority 750
+---------------------------+ |
| V1: View you want to hide | |
+---------------------------+ |  :
                              |  | constraint with priority 1000
+---------------------------+ :  : (disable it along with setting isHidden for V1)
| V2: Other view            |  
+---------------------------+
```

Or you can combine this method with removing the view.

Answer (score 0):

For completion:

To remove a view from your viewcontroller:

```
[self.yourView removeFromSuperview];
[self.yourView release];
```

This is how you should do in the OLD DAYS. But nowadays XCode has ARC (Auto Reference Count) that means the release code is no longer needed unless you explicitly require immediate release. So your code will be:

```
[self.yourView removeFromSuperview];
```

This means, the yourView will be removed from viewcontroller, but still held in memory, until that memory is needed, then iOS will auto remove it forever.

Answer (score 0):

Just design your layout using `StackView`

Now if you set one of the subviews to hidden it will no longer take up any space. You can even animate this transition and get a nice shrinking effect.